# What are the black bugs that come from defeated enemies?

Tags: freedom-planet

Sometimes when I defeat an enemy a small black bug will appear and start flying away from me. What are these black bugs? Is there something I can do with them?

[image: Black bugs from a dea]

Comment: This game has so much Sonic vibes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a parasite called **Shade Core** [image]
They can be found in two forms: Insect form and Fish form.

According to [Freedom Planet wikia](https://freedomplanet.fandom.com/wiki/Shade_Core):

> Shade Cores have the ability to house themselves into certain types of machines, thus possessing and turning some of them into the enemies that hassle the Player throughout every Stage. When the robots they are controlling are destroyed, a Shade Cores simply flies (or swims) away.
> So far, these creatures themselves cannot be destroyed by the Player, so it is unclear if a Shade Core can be destroyed at all.